# merging local and server updates

Tags: javascript, redux

Need to merge 2 lists of updates, local and server.
Using redux (but it doesn't really matter) i need to refresh the updates list.

```
const localUpdates = [
  { id: 1, name: 'one', date: 'old' },
  { id: 2, name: 'two', date: 'old' },
  { id: 3, name: 'three', date: 'old' },
];

const serverUpdates = [
  { id: 1, name: 'one', date: 'new' },
  { id: 4, name: 'four', date: 'new' },
];
```

Desired output:

```
updates: [
  { id: 1, name: 'one', date: 'new' },
  { id: 2, name: 'two', date: 'old' },
  { id: 3, name: 'three', date: 'old' },
  { id: 4, name: 'four', date: 'new' },
]
```

Thanks in advance (having brainfreeze looiking at this for the past hour)

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: Just speaking logically, one approach would be to loop over one of the update arrays.  Find a matching element by the id, and if found, update the name and dates.  If not found, add the new record, potentially with a clone.  The bigger point here though is to break down the process in to smaller steps, and work on each of those steps one at a time.

Comment: I tried a lot of things, including a nested for loop that i;m too embarassed to post here. Most of the tries i made i think will be confusing.

Comment: That's fine.  There are two primary points with us wanting to see your attempt(s).  #1) it shows us you've made an effort and are not just asking for a solution, and #2) it can help us identify where you are getting confused.  If we can identify where you are becoming confused, we can zone in on that and help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `Array.prototype.reduce` followed by `Object.values` to the concated array in order to perform an update

```js
const localUpdates = [
  { id: 1, name: 'one', date: 'old' },
  { id: 2, name: 'two', date: 'old' },
  { id: 3, name: 'three', date: 'old' },
];

const serverUpdates = [
  { id: 1, name: 'one', date: 'new' },
  { id: 4, name: 'four', date: 'new' },
];


const concatArr = localUpdates.concat(serverUpdates);
// we will be excepting new values for same id

const resObj = concatArr.reduce((acc, item)=> {
   acc[item.id] = {...(acc[item.id] || {}), ...item};
   return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(resObj));
```

Comment: What if `id = 464`?

Comment: @strdr4605 How will that make a difference,

Comment: Strange to store in an array!

Comment: @strdr4605 Were you talking about the typo in assigning second parameter to reduce?

Answer (score 1):

create a temporary object, loop over both arrays and add each object's id in the temporay object as key and whole object as value. Objects with same id's will be overwritten. Finally use `Object.values` to get the merged objects in an array.

```js
const localUpdates = [
  { id: 1, name: 'one', date: 'old' },
  { id: 2, name: 'two', date: 'old' },
  { id: 3, name: 'three', date: 'old' },
];

const serverUpdates = [
  { id: 1, name: 'one', date: 'new' },
  { id: 4, name: 'four', date: 'new' },
];

const obj = {};
localUpdates.forEach(local => (obj[local.id] = local));
serverUpdates.forEach(server => (obj[server.id] = server));


console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```